# how use media queries with iframes ? to show different iframe source based on media query

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML.

My question is, how do I show different iframes, based on the sizes of media queries?

Example:
`for @media (max-width:400px)` load iframe01 and for the rest of the sizes, load iframe02.

Any ideas, please?

My code is as follows:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 75%; /* 4:3 Aspect Ratio */
}

.responsive-iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <iframe class="responsive-iframe" src="iframe_sample"></iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible with css, you should get window width with js and set the src respectively.

Comment: Yep, it is impossible with just CSS. You need JS for what. CSS stands for "Cascading Style Sheets", so it is used for styles, not for manipulating data.

Comment: Thx for hint, so I assume that for changing img source is the same, right?  (not background img)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to achieve this.

Here is an example:

```css
html {
  background: blue;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* padding-top: 75%; */
  /* 4: 3 Aspect Ratio; */
}

.responsive-iframe,
.responsive-iframe2 {
  /* position: absolute; */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* bottom: 0; */
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  html {
    background: red;
  }
  .responsive-iframe {
    /* position: absolute; */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
  }
  .responsive-iframe2 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <iframe class="responsive-iframe" src="https://www.facebook.com/"></iframe>
      <iframe class="responsive-iframe2" src="https://twitter.com/home"></iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The iframes are broken links. However, you can give a separate ID or class to each iframe and then use the `display: none` property on the ID or class that you do not want visible.

The code I presented shows two iframes on desktop format. However, once you scale the page to 400px or less, it shows only one. I also altered the background colour for reference.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thx Robert for hint, I had  to just add  this code to show also only one iframe over 400px, `@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) `

Comment: Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: only downside is that browser is loading all iframes with `display: none`, right ?  if I have many iframes, huge loading times

Comment: `display:none` simply does not display that element on the HTML page - this means that it is still loaded. Therefore, try to avoid embedding iframes with a lot of data.

Comment: yep, so if I want to save some loading time with loading only specified iframes, I have to look for JS, right ?

Comment: I think that would be the optimal solution, yes.

Comment: btw here is my iframe site  :)   https://webcovid19.live/  ....loading times around 20-30 sec now, I want to make it also for mobile view

Comment: Cool. Try styling it a bit using CSS to make it more interactive!